# node.js with mongodb giving error on windows while creating new db

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb

Using following code snippet of node.js code connectiong mongodb running on windows:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

var db = new mongo.db("nodetest", new mongo.Server(host, port, {}));

db.open(function(error){
  console.log("connected" + host + ":" + port);
});
```

Respective error is:

```
C:\nodetest\mongo.js:5
var db = new mongo.db("nodetest", new mongo.Server(host, port, {}));
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodetest\mongo.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

C:\nodetest>
```

Same code works on ubuntu well. Any pointers?

Comment: The `node-mongodb-native` driver exports [`Db`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) (capital 'D'). I'm unsure why the code would work on Ubuntu, unless you're using another driver or perhaps a different version.

Comment: Thanks. "Db" works. But "db" is working on ubuntu. Rather I am referring to a video tutorial which uses "db" and programs runs well. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks robertklep. The problem was with "Db". But "db" works fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: There must be something else wrong, as the variable name working on one platform and not another just doesn't make sense. Maybe it's an older version or....